# Citrus-Framework: How to start/stop docker container in doFinally()?

Tags: docker, integration-testing, citrus-framework

I'd like to start a previously stopped container as a `doFinally()` action in my citrus test case.
I tried the following in my `JUnit4CitrusTestDesigner` test class (as [documented](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/finally-section.html)):

```
doFinally(docker().client(dockerClient).start("mycontainer"));
```

But my IDE already complains that `ContainerStart` is not applicable to `doFinally()`.

Is there another way to achieve this?